# Can't reverse engineer SQL Server database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to create a Web API. I'm following some examples but I can't get anything to work.

The examples say to use this

```
Scaffold-DbContext connection_string Microsoft.EntityFrameworksCore -OutputDir Models
```

I don't want to do all the tables so I looks at the "Package Manager Console" help for the command and am told this

```
-Tables <String[]>
    The tables to generate entity types for.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                @()
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

So I've tried this

```
Scaffold-DbContext connection_string Microsoft.EntityFrameworksCore -OutputDir Models -Tables dbo.table
```

I'm changing the names of the connection string and tables. I don't want to do all the tables because there are 70+ tables in this db.

When I try that all I get back is.

> "Build Failed"

That's pretty terse so when I stick on -Verbose all I get is

> Using project 'ArgusApi'.
>
> Using startup project 'ArgusApi'.
>
> Build started...
>
> Build failed.

A little more verbose, but not much.  I was getting more error messages but I cleaned those up to just this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: whats wrong with 70+ tables...and what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: 70 + tables is such a tiny database. Why can't you write t-sql scripts for it? It would take very little time. I could do that in an afternoon.

Comment: You can use Linq To Entity. With same connection string, you can decide which table you gonna generate Object Class

Comment: I really don't know what would be wrong with 70+ tables except we don't use most of them (this being a commercial product).  I have a number of desktop applications that do access this database. I'm trying to move the capabilities on line and this is my first try and I'm trying to follow the microsoft demos.

Answer (score 0):

The "Build Failed" message simply means that your project doesnt build. (In Visual Studio) Press F5 and try to build your project. If it cant be built cleanly, then when you run "Scaffold-DbContext" you will get this message.

Usually this happens because your entities/pocos are in some sort of broken state. Delete all your models so they dont break the build and try again.